# JavaScript isn't showing up on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I'm new to programming, and am trying to make a simple calculator. After writing some code, I realized that my JavaScript code wasn't showing up on my HTML page. Please tell me what's happening.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Simple GUI Calculator
    </title>
    <script src="Calculator.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
strokeWeight(1);

var x = 10;
var y = 140;
var xDiff = 113;
var yDiff =70;
var buttonSize = 40;

fill(95, 95, 95);
rect(1, 1, 398, 400);

fill(255, 255, 255);
rect(10, 10, 380, 100);

fill(5, 4, 4);

rect(x, y, buttonSize, buttonSize);
rect(x + xDiff, y, buttonSize, buttonSize);
rect(x + 2 * xDiff, y, buttonSize, buttonSize);
rect(x + 3 * xDiff, y, buttonSize, buttonSize);

rect(x, y + yDiff, buttonSize, buttonSize);
rect(x + xDiff, y + yDiff, buttonSize, buttonSize);
rect(x + 2 * xDiff, y + yDiff, buttonSize, buttonSize);
rect(x + 3 * xDiff, y + yDiff, buttonSize, buttonSize);

rect(x, y + 2 * yDiff, buttonSize, buttonSize);
rect(x + xDiff, y + 2 * yDiff, buttonSize, buttonSize);
rect(x + 2 * xDiff, y + 2 * yDiff, buttonSize, buttonSize);
rect(x + 3 * xDiff, y + 2 * yDiff, buttonSize, buttonSize);

rect(x, y + 3 * yDiff, buttonSize, buttonSize);
rect(x + xDiff, y + 3 * yDiff, buttonSize, buttonSize);
rect(x + 2 * xDiff, y + 3 * yDiff, buttonSize, buttonSize);
rect(x + 2 * xDiff + 90, y + 3 * yDiff, buttonSize + 23, buttonSize);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not showing up"  As in when you view source it's not loading?  Or is it loading but it's broken?

Comment: All of those function calls you are doing don't do anything because they don't exist. Are you certain you aren't trying to use a canvas object or something else similar for the drawing? That requires initialization and also having a `<canvas>` object on the page...

Comment: You should create an jsFiddle of this www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using canvas API, but you do not have any canvas in HTML.

Try tutorial on canvas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial. Then see documentation & libraries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I had previously been trying to code on KhanAcademy, which taught me all the wrong stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The functions you are using aren't in JavaScript per se. They are JavaScript properties and methods of the canvas object in HTML 5. You can use this link to find out how to access a canvas object and use your code as methods applied to the canvas object that you will have created. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp